# Execution context of the ' this ' keyword in clone function implementation

Tags: javascript

I was looking into a function that creates a copy of provided object. I understand mostly what's happening except for the line that involves `this` keyword. I do understand that the original design of the `this` keyword was meant to point to an instance of an object in class definitions if we go back to the origins of the `this` keyword that was borrowed from `C++`. But JavaScript decided to use `this` keyword to provide one extra feature, carrying a link to execution context. In the following example I am trying to understand why are we using `this` keyword. If you have any thoughts, I would really appreciate it.

```
function clone(obj) {
  const replace = {};
  let idx = 0;

  const undefCache = [];

  const replacer = (key, value) => {
    let result;
    if (value === undefined) {
      result = '__undefined__';
    } else if (typeof value === 'symbol' || typeof value === 'function') {
      const keyIdx = `__replaced__${idx}`;
      idx += 1;
      replace[keyIdx] = [this, key]; // I understand mostly what's happening except for the line
      result = keyIdx;
    } else {
      result = value;
    }
    return result;
  };

  function reviver(key, value) {
    let result;
    if (value === '__undefined__') {
      undefCache.push([this, key]);// I understand mostly what's happening except for the line
    } else if (replace[value] !== undefined) {
      result = replace[value][0][key];
    } else {
      result = value;
    }
    return result;
  }

  const json = JSON.stringify(obj, replacer);
  console.log(json);
  const newObject = JSON.parse(json, reviver);
  undefCache.forEach(el => {
    const [o, key] = el;
    o[key] = undefined;
  });
  return newObject;
}

const source = {
  a: 2,
  b: '2',
  c: false,
  g: [
    { a: { j: undefined }, func: () => {} },
    { a: 2, b: '2', c: false, g: [{ a: { j: undefined }, func: () => {} }] }
  ]
};

const targetOne = clone(source);
console.log(targetOne);
```

Comment: Look at the *caller* API / contracts to find out what `this` is setup to be - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse - ".. Then [reviver] is called, with the object containing the property being processed as `this`, and with the property name as a string, and the property value as arguments ..". In this case, consider that it's really no different than a fancier way of expressing `function reviver(objectWithProperty, key, value)..`, except the `objectWithProperty` is accessed via `this`.

Comment: It may also be interesting to read over `Function.call/Function.apply`, as these allow changing `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used to handle nested objects when doing serialization/deserialization with `JSON.parse`/`stringify` on special values.

Within the replacer/reviver functions, the `this` context is the current object that the serializer (`stringify`) or deserializer (`parse`) is working on.

For example, for the object below:

```
myObject = {
    "foo": {
        "bar": function () {}
    },
    "bar": "Different bar"
}
```

When it's processing the item `myObject["foo"]["bar"]`, `this` inside the replacer will be a reference to `myObject["foo"]` with `key = "bar"` and `value = function () {}"`. This is useful because without the reference, we wouldn't know whether we were processing `myObject["bar"]` or `myObject["foo"]["bar"]`.

Thus when it is saved into the array, it really just saved `pair = [myObject["foo"], "bar"]`. Later when it's recovered, for each of these pairs, it can just do `pair[0][pair[1]]` to recover `myObject["foo"]["bar"]`.

This works similarly with the reviver and undefined. Here the problem is that the reviver cannot return `undefined` and have the value set to undefined, so instead the code snippet remembers which keys are like this and post-processes the copy of the object to set them properly.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter

Comment: Thank you for a straightforward explanation!